# How to use getQ and putQ in template haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, template-haskell

I would like to handle states in Q monad with Template Haskell.
According to some stack overflow's answers, there is a solution that uses `unsafePerformIO`, but I want to avoid using it as long as I can.

I found `getQ` and `putQ` in the module [`Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.10.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html). These functions handle states in Q monad shown by template-haskell 2.10 document.
I tried to use this API, but `getQ` fails to get states.

Following code is an example of my problem.
I expects `x` to be bounded to `(Just B)`,but `x` is always `Nothing`.

```
-- X.hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
module X where
import Data.Typeable
data T = A | B | C deriving (Typeable,Show)


-- Y.hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Y where
import X
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax
-- splice for testing getQ and putQ
do
  putQ B
  x <- getQ :: Q (Maybe T)
  runIO $ print x -- prints Nothing
  return []
```

as a result , I got following compile message.

```
$ ghc -fforce-recomp Y.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling X                ( X.hs, X.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Y                ( Y.hs, Y.o )
Nothing
```

How to use `getQ` and `putQ`?

Answer (score 1):

There's currently a bug in getQ: it was recently fixed and should be working in the next version of GHC.